# jquery .delay() not doing stuff

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i have made a modal and added a close button to it so when its clicked it adds a class to the modal the trigges the closing modal animation but then i tryed the remove the class again but its doing nothing

this is my code

```
$('.close').on('click', function(){
$(this)
  .parent().addClass("closing")
  .delay(3250)
  .queue(function() {
     $(this).parent().removeClass('closing');
     $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
     $(this).dequeue();
 });
});
```

i added a console log to see if the .delay works and it dose it seem it cant find the right ellement to remove the classes from

Comment: I guess you are trying to use outer function **this**, so better add it to a variable and use. Like: `var _this = this` and use it like: `$(_this).parent().removeClass('closing');`

Comment: Because inside queue, you are targeting the parent of element you have added class

Comment: @Abhi Or just use `$(this).removeClass('closing')` in queue callback

Comment: Can you show us your HTML code?

Comment: this is my full code http://pastebin.com/SEEM6bJF

Comment: @A.Wolff thx for the tip and fix :D

Answer (score 2):

Because of chaining, this variable inside `.queue()` will refer to the parent of `.close` element.

```
$('.close').on('click', function () {
    $(this) // Initial element.
        .parent().addClass("closing") // this refers  to$(this).parent()
        .delay(3250)
        .queue(function () {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('closing'); // This refers to $(this).parent().parent()
        $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
        $(this).dequeue();
    });
});
```

**Solution**

```js
  $('.close').on('click', function() {

    $(this).parent().addClass("closing")
      .delay(3250)
      .queue(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('open closing').dequeue();
      });
  });
```

```css
    .closing {
      background: red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
    lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
    facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  <button class="close">Close</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `A callback in .queue() will be called in different context` No, that's wrong, jQuery keeps chaining

Comment: right...has nothing to do with the method `queue()` but with the object that was passed to the method. Context will be whatever object was passed to it. Your statement is a bit misleading

Comment: @A.Wolff true, I'll fix my answer. Thank you!

Comment: As a side note, this statement `A callback in setTimeout() will be called in different context` is true, maybe that's what mislead you :)

Comment: have nested click handlers

Comment: @A.Wolff I meant that it is called in different context, comparing to the first `this` @charlietfl fixed, thanks!

Comment: @halfzebra ok my bad then!

Answer (score 1):

When you see yourself writing `$(this)` several times in an event handler you should cache that object as variable for efficiency to minimize function calls as well as make code easier to read

The new named variable then makes it easier to know exactly what element you stored when you start getting into other `this` context also which is what is happening to you now. In your situation you have an `this` which is the element and then inside the queue callback `this` refers to the initial element's parent which is what is confusing you.

Simple fix...cache reference to parent.

```
$('.close').on('click', function () {

    var $parent = $(this).parent();

    $parent.addClass("closing")
           .delay(3250)
           .queue(function () {
               $parent.removeClass('open closing').dequeue();    
            });
});
```

In this case what you really would want to cache is the parent

Comment: OP is using `$(this).parent()` and use `queue()` method on this element, so inside `queue()` callback, `$(this)` is referring to former `$(this).parent()`

Comment: @A.Wolff I realize that...is one and the same. No reason to need to use `this` inside `queue` if you already have a jQuery object for `$(this)` cached